# SharePoint 2013 How to calculate results from sum of two columns

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Instead of using the predefined total options(sum, count, average, maximum, minimum, stdev)  I would like to create my own formula and place it in a similar position. Here is a picture of what I was referencing.

[image]

What I would like to do is perform a calculation based on two columns and their sums to generate a new result.

In excel it looks like this: `=SUM(F13:F17)/(Sum(D13:D17)*3)`.

**Basically**, I just want the `sum of two entire columns`, do some simple division and multiplication, and generate a new result.

If I could place this result above like the predefined totals that came with SharePoint that would be great or somewhere else works. I just need this result to appear somewhere in the list.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Edit: In a calculated column, how do I select more than just 1 row? I would like to select all of the rows.

Answer (score 1):

All answers in this topic *skin the cat*

### The non-Designer, non-JSlink, non-Data View WebPart way

By [whacking some HTML & JavaScript in a **Calculated Column**](http://viewmaster365.com/#/How)

You can get this:

[image]

Not suggested for large volume lists, but fine for Views that fit in your display.

Note: It only **displays** in  **View**, it is not a new Fied value you can continue with

Takes 9 steps and some 15 minutes (or 2 if you just copy/paste the last step)

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum

Comment: Hi Danny. I'm a little confused by your post. Do I need to download some software before I can begin following these steps?

Comment: If you are confused then its probably not for you. You don't need any software, no Designer, no Visual Studio, just **carefull** have to paste code in a Calculated Column.... But as I said... if you don't know what to do then this is not something that matches your skilllevel (and I think even JSLink is easier for you to apply then)

Comment: I added it to my bar, then went to my list and clicked on it and it worked. It was added to my style library. Then when I went onto my list and looked in list settings I didn't see anything related to the viewmaster.

Comment: The ViewMaster does Priority, PercentComplete, Date, NOT the Sum you asked for., That you have to create yourself with the documented steps: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/Sum

Answer (score 0):

You can use `calculated column` in that case.

- For the `Total` you can `edit in the View - Total Scores - Select the Calculated Column`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'm familiar with calculated column but not for this specific example. What syntax would I use to get the sum of an entire column? (there are 5 rows with values in this column I want to add up and divide)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a JSLink file and attaching it to the List View webpart using the webpart properties pane.

Inside the JSLink file you can use somethhing like below

```
var _totalValue1 = 0.0;
var _totalValue2 = 0.0;
(function () {
    var calculatedFieldCtx = {};       
    calculatedFieldCtx.Templates = {};   
    calculatedFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "FieldOne": {
            "View": Calculated1
        },
        "FieldTwo": {
            "View": Calculated2
        }
    };   
    calculatedFieldCtx.OnPostRender = [];
    calculatedFieldCtx.OnPostRender.push(function()
    {
        var result = _totalValue1 + _totalValue2 / 3;
        alert(result);
    });
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        calculatedFieldCtx
    ); 
})();


function Calculated1(ctx) {       
    _totalValue1 += parseFloat((ctx.CurrentItem.FieldOne));
    return ctx.CurrentItem.FieldOne;
}

function Calculated2(ctx) {       
    _totalValue2 += parseFloat((ctx.CurrentItem.FieldTwo));
    return ctx.CurrentItem.FieldTwo;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not very familiar with JSLink. I'm looking to solve this using SharePoint online

Comment: It works with SPO also.. You can achieve your requirement only via JSOM or JSLink.

Comment: @AmalHashim but your approach will only show the sum per page and not per list is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Mark Rackley posted a very good [explanation](http://www.markrackley.net/2010/03/31/sharepoint-summing-calculated-columns-by-groups-dvwp/) of how to do this with SharePoint Designer.

Basically, you use a Data View Web Part to display your information and you can customize the look to show your formulated total.

Comment: Thank you for the link! It seems the screencast http://www.screencast.com/users/EndUserSharePoint/folders/SharePoint%20-%20Data%20View%20Web%20Part/media/9b4f373b-530e-4abc-9daa-90549b9b5642 is buggy and no longer works though?

Comment: That is a link on Mark's site to which I am not responsible.  The link, according to the article is from Laura Rogers.  Her blog has moved, and thus your broken link.  It can be googled and found here. https://wonderlaura.com/2010/03/31/summing-calculated-columns/